# Como partilhar/passar dados entre activities sem ser por Intent?

Tags: android

Eu tenho uma aplicação do Android Studio onde, ao clicar em um botão, um número é gerado na Activity A e armazenado em outro botão na Activity B, que é sobrescrito sempre que eu gero um número novo na Acitivty A. Será que é necessário usar mySQL pra isso ou há outro método?

*Eu /Não/ quero iniciar a Activity B sempre que enviar o número para ela. Quero apenas armazená-lo sem precisar ir para a tela, mas que ele continue lá quando eu desejar ir.

**Por favor não sejam muito técnicos, pois ainda estou me familiarizando com o android studio

Answer (score 1):

Não existe forma (segura) de uma Activity "conversar" diretamente com outra Activity. Da forma que o Android é arquitetado, diferentes Activities e Services podem estar em processos separados.

Se você quisesse abrir a outra Activity, disparar um Intent seria a forma correta. Mas como você não quer, minha sugestão é gravar o valor gerado na Activity A na configuração do app:

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
prefs = PreferenceManager.
        getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
ed.putInt("numero", x);
ed.apply();
```

Na Activity B você pode ler o valor da configuração:

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
prefs = PreferenceManager.
        getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
int x = prefs.getInt("numero", defaultx);
```

Também é possível a Actiivty B inscrever-se para receber notificações quando a configuração for mudada pela Activity A:

```
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

neste caso sua Activity deve implementar uma interface, e a declaração fica parecida com:

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity
      implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
```

e você deve declarar o método que vai ser chamado quando alguma config mudar:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
         SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if (key.equals("numero")) {
        ... numero mudou, atualizar o botao ....
    }
}
```